# 410 code not getting captured but throwing error instead

Tags: c#, web-services, http, stream, httpwebrequest

I got this code which is trying to capture 410 code, but it's throwing error at first line and not going through rest of the code,

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Gone)
            {
```

Is there any way I can capture the 410 code other then above one.

**Answer code with help of answer below**

```
  try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
               if (((HttpWebResponse)(ex.Response)).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound || ((HttpWebResponse)(ex.Response)).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Gone)
                {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `GetResponse` method works. It throws an exception when it does not get code `200`.

Try to put your `request.GetResponse()` into `try .. catch` block. Catch `WebException`. In `catch` clause you can handle situation, when the status code is not `200`.

```
try 
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
    var exStatusCode = ex.Code //check the status code against this
    var exResponse = ex.Response //use your response like this
}
```

Comment: so in catch block i use,    if (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Gone , sorry not sure, an example code will do the job, thanks :)

Comment: if i put in catch block i get this, Use of unassigned local variable 'response'

Comment: You should not use `response` as you did not get it correctly on that point. Use `WebException.Response` istead, so if you named your exception variable as `ex` you should use `ex.Response`

Comment: Error 2 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Net.WebResponse' and 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode'

Comment: To compare with status code use `ex.Code` like in example I posted in my answer..